# Android KInvey How to query details from multiple collections in a single query

Tags: android, kinvey, mbaas

I am developing an enterprise app using Kinvey 3.0.4 for android minsdk 15. Ihave two collections CollectionA, CollectionB which contain related data. I want to have a single query through which I can retrive data from both collections (all data or few necessary data). 
Is it possible? 
Following below link https://devcenter.kinvey.com/android/guides/datastore.
Please let me know any link that could help about relational data handling. Sample would be appreciated. 
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arti,

We've been encouraging customers away from relational models when possible as we're backed by Mongo which itself is non-relational. Relational data support is deprecated at this point. If you need to do references you can build your own in Business Logic https://devcenter.kinvey.com/android/guides/business-logic#

Kinvey is backed by Mongo which does not support relationships out of the box. Instead, we encourage developers to denormalize their data. Our scale makes it so it doesn't matter how many rows or columns you store in each collection.

Our engineering team put together an article to help folks understand how we think about data on NoSQL: https://devcenter.kinvey.com/android/guides/data-modeling# I'd recommend reading this.

Thanks,
Pranav

Comment: Hi Pranav, thank you for quick reply, things are bit clear about Relational data. So trying with standard way. I've hooked a file on console, but not getting how to access it in my android code. Would you please tell me how to use hooked file?